# Understanding and navigating Mark / Mark not set

Tags: vimrc, mark

Sometimes I enter in characters and my screen shows "Mark not set", and it seems like I have to either press escape or q a bunch of times to get out of that 'mode'. So, related to this:

- What does 'Mark not set' mean?
- How is it that I'm normally coming across that (for example, what keys am I probably unknowingly pressing to get there?)
- Once that happens, what's the quickest way to 'dismiss' that and get back to a normal mode?

Comment: You might also want to enable `:set showcmd` in your vimrc. That will show you any pending normal-mode commands (such as `'` or `\`` for marks) in the last line in the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ways to jump to a mark are

- `'m` jump to line of mark `m`
- `` `m `` jump to line and column of mark `m`
- you can technically do `:'m`, since the range `:'m` is the line of mark `m`, and entering a range as an ex command goes to the first line (or last, if one is provided).

More at `:help mark-motions`

I usually hit `<Esc>` or `<C-c>`.